# Is there any option to get this issue resolved as I can only think of OR statement in Edit conditional Formula on sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have created Columns by click on adding Columns on share point. So Columns are (Request, budget, investment, window). Now in Request Column we have a,b,c,d,e,f choices. So I have added them as choices. We want if in Request Column value a or b or c or d or e or f is selected then only it will show remaining columns like budget, investment, window. Else it will not show further Columns to enter any details over there.

I have tried If([$Question1]== 'a','true','false') By doing that its giving all columns after entering 'a' in Request Column else its not showing any further Columns . So I have tried If([$Request]== 'a','true','false') so It it giving me error as enter valid condition that is first issue.

Now second is I have tried Or condition writing as If(OR([$Question1]-- 'a', [Question1]== 'b'), 'true','false') Its also giving me enter valid condition and I am entering those condition in NEW>Edit> going to Budget and edit conditional Formula.

Still no answer. So basically just I want that if value is select in Request Column then it will show further Columns else won't show any further columns to enter details in it

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the conditional formula in below format for `OR` conditions:

```
=if([$Request] == 'a' || [$Request] == 'a' || [$Request] == 'c', 'true', 'false')
```

Where `[$Request]` is an **internal name** of your "Request" column in SharePoint list in this format: `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`.

You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

You can add other conditions in the formula as per your requirements.

---

**Update**:

Check below Microsoft official documentation articles for formula syntax and more information:

1. [SharePoint - Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)
2. [SharePoint formatting syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked just wanted to know if you can suggest me the site from where I can get this correct syntax because I have seen this one earlier that was not correct syntax statement it was using OR. So If you can suggest me webiste or page to get correct sharepoint conditional formula syntax or all kinds that will be great.    Thank you !!

Comment: Check updated answer for documentation links